# Modifiquei a URL base do magento e sumiu tudo

Tags: magento

Criei uma loja virtual tudo em `meudominio.com.br/aroma2/ma_pharmacy/` e agora queria mudar tudo para somente `dominio.com.br`.

Fui em `configuração/web` e alterei a URL base achando que daria certo, porém além de o site sumir não consigo acessar o *admin* do magento mais.

O que eu faço agora? Perdi todo meu trabalho?

Answer (score 1):

Verifique a tabela app_config_data
Altere as urls na mão se for necessário.

Só uma pergunta, seu ecommerce está em um diretório dentro de outro site?
se for esse o caso você terá que criar um sub-domínio e redirecionar seu domínio para ele

Espero ter ajudado

Answer (score 0):

Boa Tarde,

possivelmente é cache, delete os arquivos da pasta var/cache e limpe também o cache do seu navegador.

Abra seu banco de dados e faça o TRUMCATE das seguintes tabelas:
log_url 
log_url_info 
log_visitor 
log_visitor_info

Caso tenha colocado URL errada é possível trocar executando o seguinte SQL no seu banco de dados:

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://urlteste.com.br/' WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url'; 

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://urlteste.com.br/' WHERE path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

Após esses procedimentos teste novamente sua loja.